# The type initializer for 'DotNetOpenAuth.Logger' threw an exception

Tags: powershell, dotnetopenauth, google-api-dotnet-client

My aim is to call Google Admin SDK Directory updates from PowerShell.  I started out with a working .NET app and converted it into a class library (which I tested - it works).  I load that in the module manifest with

```
RequiredAssemblies = @('My.GoogleAdminSDK.Directory.dll')
```

My Get-GoogleSDKUser function New-Objects my class and calls GetUser on it.  And I get:

```
Exception calling "GetUser" with "1" argument(s): "The type initializer for 
'DotNetOpenAuth.Logger' threw an exception."
At C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\My.googleadminsdkdirectory.admin\My.GoogleA
dminSDKDirectory.Admin.psm1:56 char:9
+         $service.GetUser($googleUserName)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeInitializationException
```

I've tried adding a config file for log4net which has produced an empty log file but that didn't help.

**Note**: in order to get this far, I had to add

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.12.0" newVersion="1.2.12.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

to powershell_ise.exe.config to prevent the error:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives,
>   Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

which is far from ideal.

**EDIT**

The InnerException for the PowerShell-calling-my-DLL version was:

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0,
>   Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

It took a bit of digging to find the innerException.  I had a bit of a ferret around and found suggestions to use Fuslogvw, so I tried that.  I closed and re-opened PowerShell, started up Fusion Log Viewer (it's the first time I've used it) and found three entries for log4net.  The descriptions are:

- log4net
- log4net, Version=1.2.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a
- log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821

When I open them up, the first two have 'The operation was successful.' as the second line of text.  The third has 'The operation failed. Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.'

When I dig into that log, I find:

```
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\JLP.GoogleAdminSDKDirectory.Admin\log4net.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: log4net, Version=1.2.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build Number
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
```

I tried running it from Visual Studio again.  There were also three entries in fuslogvw and the third had the same error.  But there's nothing in the VS output to indicate a problem.

Comment: You should be able to see the inner exception which caused the type initializer exception. That will have more information about what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks.  The innerException shows that it's not able to load the file because the version is different and the assembly redirection in the config file is for a different PublicKeyToken.  Is it normal to change this for every version?  Is there a way round it?

Comment: I'm not an expert on that, but I *think* it sounds like the author has changed the key they're using to sign it. I suggest you see if you can get the correct original version.

Comment: Indeed they have.  In fact, they are maintaining both keys.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the two versions of log4net with different PublicKeyTokens have caused problems for others.  I've got it working by adding a verison of log4netwith  PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821 to the GAC and adding another bindingredirect to the config file because the versions didn't match.

You can find the log4net versions [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download_log4net.cgi).  You'll see references to oldkey and newkey versions.  The oldkey one has PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821 so I simply ran

```
gacutil /i "C:\Users\Me\Downloads\log4net\log4net-1.2.12-bin-oldkey\log4net-1.2.12\b
in\net\4.0\release\log4net.dll"
```

to stick it in the GAC and added:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="1b44e1d426115821" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.12.0" newVersion="1.2.12.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

to the assemblyBindings in the config file.